# Who are really the people in the photo found in the Soviet installation

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

In *Rise of The Tomb Raider*, one of the secret items(relics) hidden near the soviet installation is a photo of a family. When Lara analyzes the photo, she reads the word *Remember* on the back (seems it's not written in English).

My question is, it's a real photo of real people. Who are they?

Here is the picture:
[image: Here is the picture]

[image: This is the back of the picture]

Comment: It's about the content of the game. I don't see how that is "off-topic".

Comment: You're not asking about content in the game.  You're asking about real life stuff that, while it has a bearing in the game, is not actually about the game.

Comment: I just edited the question. Please check. You also might want to take a look at this: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11270/is-it-ok-to-ask-about-the-origin-of-contents-of-the-game-in-real-life

Comment: "seems it's not in English" - considering it's of a Russian family, I'm guessing the word is Russian for "remember", in some conjugation. Also, its entirely possible the photo was created for the game, and may just be like random models/actors/etc they paid to pose/dress for the photo.

Answer (score 5):

The only match in a reverse image search is from [a genealogy page on the 100th birthday of Steve Miklo (2013)](http://miklofamily.blogspot.no/2013/03/uncle-jan.html). Steve's father moved to the United States and eventually gave his land to his brother, Ján (Steve's uncle). Steve came to live with them. The blog's maintainer dates the photo in question to the 1940s in [Drahovce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drahovce) ([western Slovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trnava_Region)). Steve's Uncle Ján and Aunt Marie sit in the front row and are surrounded by their children (but not Steve).

There does not appear to be any connection between a member of the Miklo family and Crystal Dynamics, though perhaps one between Google Images and Russian family photos.

[image: Miklo family]

Answer (score -2):

I just think these people  who made Crystal Dynamics found this photo in real life and switched up all the details about this family to make it seem like it's  any "real" photo, but it's not, it's just their version of the photo.

Comment: The existing answer already disproves this.